# Getting Email address of a Sharepoint 2010 PeoplePicker Column Value in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

I have a list which has a "Person/Group" column which allows multiple values. I have added some of the users in that column also. Now I want to get the email address of these users using a powershell command. When I try to display the column name using:

```
Write-Host $item["To"]
```

The result is like:

```
70;#Anand, Amit 25;#Kumar, Prabhakar
```

It is displaying like a string. How do I get the person field email id in Powershell? I have searched the web, but I could not find any solid solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = "70;#Anand, Amit 25;#Kumar, Prabhakar 982;#Owen, Martin D."
$regex = "(?<id>\d+);#(?<name>[.\D]*)"

$input | Select-String $regex -AllMatches | % {
    ForEach($match in $_.Matches) {
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            Id = $match.groups["id"].value
            Name = $match.groups["name"].value
        }
    }
}
```

Should give you:

```
Id      Name                                                                              
--      ----                                                                              
70      Anand, Amit                                                                       
25      Kumar, Prabhakar 
982     Owen, Martin D.
```

I've only tested this in PowerShell 3.0, but I think it should work in 2.0.

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks for your reply, but i want the email address.. the result should be like Anand.Amit@gmail.com, Kumar.Prabhakar@gmail.com...would you please guide me..??

Comment: Its going to be a bit harder than that, you need to instantiate a SPUserfieldvalue, then from there get a SPUser and then you can get the email.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
$web = get-spweb http://sptwd

"70;#Anand, Amit 25;#Kumar, Prabhakar".Split(",") | ForEach {
    $userValue = New-Object Microsoft.Sharepoint.SPFieldUserValue ($web,$_)
    $email = $userValue.User.Email
}
```

You might need to trim the spaces after the comma